# Android WebView: Disable Scroll Yellow Edge Gradient

Tags: android, webview, scroll, scrollview

How do I disable the little yellow gradient that shows up when you scroll the view to the top or bottom. The yellow gradient comes in when you've reached the bounds of the scrollable area, and if you try and keep scrolling the gradient starts showing more and more.

I've tried using the "setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false)" but that doesn't work.

For reference this is how I setup my webview:

```
isiWebView = (WebView)_view.findViewById(R.id.isiWebView);
isiWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
isiWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/isi.html");
isiWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
isiWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this,"JSInterface");
isiWebView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you can try to set over scroll mode:

```
isiWebView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```